# Is there a way to bind an event to all nested models with Backbone and/or Backbone-Relational?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework, backbone-events, backbone-relational

I have a pretty beefy BackboneRelational - model that has numerous nested models and collections. Basically if the user changes anything about this model or it's sub-models/collections, I need to do something in the UI to indicate this. So I'd like a master change event that would fire no matter sub-model changed. Is there an easy way to do this? I wrote a function that recursively traverses all of my models and adds a change events but I have problems with binding to the same model twice, race conditions, etc..

Comment: Take a look at this question answered by @Derick Bailey: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843278/fire-an-event-from-one-view-to-another-in-backbone -- basically, this gives you a pub/sub pattern that you can publish any change from your models, and listen to those from anything else.

Comment: @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩 this question isn't about `dom-events`, backbone has it's own event system

Comment: @TJ Thanks for the heads-up. I'll watch out for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using Backbone.Events. `var object = {};_.extend(object, Backbone.Events)`