# Backbone.View: Delete different views related to different models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational, backbone-views

I need to display `three different views` which are related to `three different model` or collections.
In order to perform this task I wrote the following code. (*)
Please tell me if it is the right way to make this, anyway it works.

Here my problem.
In one of this view, let's say the `firstView`, is possible to perform a `DELETE request` to the server which  take care to delete all the data related to this `three view`.

Now I need to delete my three view… 
but from the `firstView` I cannot access to the others two views.

1) How can I perform this task?
2) Should I redesign/improve my implementation?

---

(*)

```
// module for display three different views

define([
    "js/views/01View",
    "js/views/02View",
    "js/views/03View"
], function (FirstView, SecondView, ThirdView) {

    var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function ()
        {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function ()
        {
            var movie_id = this.options.movie_id;
            this.firstView = new FirstView(movie_id);
            this.secondView = new SecondView(movie_id);
            this.thirdView = new ThirdView(movie_id);
        }
    });    

    return MainView;
});
```

---

P.S.:

The _id is used to build the url parameter of collections or models

```
url1: http://localhost/movie/movie_id   (model1)
url2: http://localhost/movie/movie_id/followers   (collection2)
ulrs: http://localhost/movie/movie_id/feeds (collection3)
```

When I delete the model1 the view2 and view3 related to collection2 and collection3 should be removed.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment, you say that you have three different views and three different models, yet you pass the same model_id to your views.

Comment: model_id (the same id) is used to perform three different fetch to the server which corresponds to three different data model. I will add more information on my question.

Comment: feels like you're constructing your data around your views rather than your views around your data. Take a look at the following Backbone plugin: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/ and set up your relationship between your data correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right, maybe because the html and the restapi was ready and I was in charge of implementing bb. Anyway do you think the only way to fix the problem is to use Backbone-relational? Would be great for me to have a quick solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit your problem based on our comments conversation, Backbone architecture revolves using events, so why not use an event aggregator to send events around, don't limit yourself to the backbone constructs. [fire an event from one view to another in backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843278/fire-an-event-from-one-view-to-another-in-backbone) This pattern provides an elegant solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Views` should not respond to direct method calls but to events. Said that you either create a common `EventAggregator` accesible from every View (as @20100 has explained in his answer) or you connect the Views through a **common Model** and make each View to *listen* to its own more *interesting* events on it.

In your case you can instantiate the Movie model out of the Views instantiations and connect the three Views around it:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function ( opts ) {
    this.movie = new Movie({ id: this.opts.movie_id} )
    this.movie.fetch();
    this.render();
  },

  render: function () {
    this.firstView = new FirstView( this.movie );
    this.secondView = new SecondView( this.movie );
    this.thirdView = new ThirdView( this.movie );
  }
});

var ThirdView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function( opts ) {
    this.movie = opts.movie;
    this.movie.on( "destroy", this.cleanUp, this )
    this.followers = // fetch the followers as you do now, use this.model.id
  }

  cleanUp: function(){
    // your clean up code when model is detroyed
  }
});
```

Comment: I like the idea of an `EventAggregator`, but in your code I cannot see where I have to put it. I suppose in `MainView` and then pass it as parameter to the other views. Is it right?

Comment: I'm not explaining the idea of the `EventAggregator`, @20100 does it. But if very similar, instead of having a common `Model` you have a common `EventAggregator`, follow the link in the @20100`s answer.