# Getting a reference to a model in an event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, first time playing with Backbone.js.

I have two views with two models and I want to use the [event aggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7843636/74022) method to fire events between the two.

The aggregator declaration:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

So in one view I have a line like this that will fire the `removeRow` method.

```
this.eventAggregator.trigger("removeRow", this.row);
```

In another view

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.eventAggregator.bind("removeRow", this.removeRow);
      this.model.get("rows").each(function(row) {
        // Do stuff
      }); 
    },
    removeRow: function(row) {
       // row is passed in fine
       // this.model is undefined
       this.model.get("rows").remove(row);
    }
});
```

I think I understand why `this.model` is undefined, but what can I do to maintain a reference so that I can use `this.model` in the callback? I thought about passing the model to the first view and then passing it back in the `trigger` call, but that seems to make the entire point of an event aggregator pointless. If I have the model I can just call the `.remove` method directly and have lost the benefit of my first view being unaware of the model. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have *binding* problem.

You have two ways to assure that `this` will be the *View instance*:

#### 1. Using `bindAll`

In your `View.initialize()` you can add this line:

```
_.bindAll( this, "removeRow" )
```

[Interesting post of @DerickBailey about this matter](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/06/15/solving-backbones-this-model-view-problem-with-underscore-js/)

#### 2. Using the optional third argument in your bind declaration

Like this:

```
this.eventAggregator.bind("removeRow", this.removeRow, this);
```

[Backbone documentation about this matter](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this)

Comment: I like this one the most too. It is most explicit and easily understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Supply your View object as third parameter of the bind method:

```
this.eventAggregator.bind("removeRow", this.removeRow, this);
```

The third parameter is the context of calling your callback. See the [docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on).

Also, you can use **.on()** instead of **.bind()** which is shorter...

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this` so scope isn't lost. The blog link on the other answer uses underscore's `bindAll`

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'removeRow');
  this.eventAggregator.bind("removeRow", this.removeRow);
  this.model.get("rows").each(function(row) {
    // Do stuff
  }); 
},
```