# PubSub with Backbone Boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, publish-subscribe

**Problem:**

I have 3 UI components on a screen:

1. **Top menu**: Option (true or false)
2. **Left menu**: list of items such as A, B, C, D
3. **Form content**: a form. It's **visible** or **hidden** depending on value of `Top menu's Option`. Its inner content varies depending on which `Left menu's item` being selected. For example, A selected will show 2 input boxes while B would show 3 input boxes, etc...

The way it works is that user will select left menu item, then they click Top menu's Option and the Form content will show up.

**Top menu** has `TopMenu` model

```
{
isSelected: false
}
```

**Left menu** has `LeftMenuCollection` which contains such model

```
{
id: 0
label: "No label yet"
}
```

**Form content** has `FormContentModel` which is too long to put in here.

I have the 2 views: `TopMenuView` and `LeftMenuView` for `TopMenu` and `LeftMenuCollection`. But the view for Form content view (let call `FormContentView`) has to get values from both `TopMenu` and `LeftMenuCollection` in order to know **when** to be visible and **what** to show after being visible.

**Current Idea:**

1. User's action on `LeftMenuView` will trigger event and `FormContentView` will populate HTML in the hidden DOM according to what being selected.
2. `TopMenuView` will trigger `FormContentView` to be **visible**.
3. Then `FormContentView` will be save into its own `FormContentCollection`.

For #1 and #2, I just has use the PubSub model like here: [fire an event from one view to another in backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843278/fire-an-event-from-one-view-to-another-in-backbone)

But since I use Backbone Boilerplate https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate. I am planning to do this because the app object is already created in app.js:

```
app.PubSub = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)
```

**Question:**

How and where do I create that PubSub object? Is it in the router.js?

Is PubSub the right way to do this? I was thinking about of "composite model" too by combining `TopMenu` and `LeftMenuCollection` under another `FormContentCollection` but most people on internet said using PubSub.

Comment: Another idea of adding a 3rd Collection object and use that to keep the "state" of "what is selected": http://hastebin.com/ginesusoce.coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the pubsub as soon as you define your "app" variable.

I prefer to attach the PubSub directly to the Backbone object and I do it right after backbone loads. (I written about it before: [Backbone.js global notifications](http://berzniz.com/post/19351578959/backbone-js-global-notifications))

**Here's another idea that might be simpler:**

Create a new model and share it between all views.

(Note that you can add a second model to views, they don't have to be set to view.model)

The Left and Top views can .set() its attributes and the Form view can bind to changes using .on('change', function...) and respond by showing/hiding the view.

Comment: Your link is great. I added `app.notif = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);` in app.js and pass this to Views `var myView = new MyView({notif: app.notif})`. So within the View object, I just do this `this.options.notif.trigger`. Very useful! Thanks.